# I can't run java files on my Notepad++, it shows "CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:"

Tags: java, notepad++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8DQZ.png)

It seems compile well, but when it run seems not well.

p.s. Eclipse can run well, I mean my JRE install has no problem, so I think the bug has connection with my Notepad++.

Comment: You are missing a space between the ``-cp`` and the ``C:\``.

Comment: The problem seems to come from the character escaping. How do you launch the execution?

Comment: javac -encoding UTF-8 "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"                                java -cp"$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)"                                        It's my script,is there any problem.

Comment: I just find my error.....I lose a ";" in the end of my path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned earlier, there is a space missing:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" java -cp"$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)" 
                                                     ^ here
```

It should be

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" java -cp "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)"
```

Comment: you mean there add a space?

Comment: Thanks for your answer sincerely!